# How do I disable the TODO marker annotation in the right margin in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tags, editor

In Eclipse, the right margin shows a little colored box for each occurance of various things in the file.  TODO is one of those markers.
I've inherited a large project with many thousands of old TODO's - which renders them nearly useless.
I've added my own TODO_CONCERN tag, and eclipse now also marks those - but they are usually lost in the noise of the old TODO tags.

I've removed TODO from Java-Compiler-Task Tags, and General-Editors-Structured Text Editor-Task Tags, but it still adds the little colored blocks for them.

Is there ANY way to make it STOP doing that for "TODO", but continue working for my "TODO_CONCERN" tag?

Comment: It is possible to filter different ToDo's in IntelliJ, but I'm not sure about eclipse

Comment: In Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations the Tasks entry controls where the Todos are shown - but you can't separate the two types of Todo.

Answer (score 2):

All task tags like TODO, FIXME etc has the same annotation colour and handled as single unit.
You can control the colour of text, their appearance in overview/vertical ruler BUT this  applies to all tags.

It is not possible to choose different colours for TODO_CONCERN and TODO.

Go to `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`

### [image]

**Workarounds**

---

1. In Tasks view delete all TODO's and commit and tag/branch in SCM as to_do_removed, do it for TOD0_CONCERNS and tag/branch as to_d0_concern. You can merge/checkout and manage.
2. Use Search and Replace option. Find all // TODO 's and replace with // TODO1 [This can be done, folder,package,project levels] then these tags are converted to normal comments, so you can see only TODO_CONCERNS in vertical/overview ruler.

Comment: So, what you also seem to be implying is that the keyword "TODO" is hard coded in Eclipse, and it doesn't matter if you remove it from all preference settings.  It will STILL have the annotation color applied to lines that contain it.
Is that correct?

Comment: No, just that ones that are set to be detected are displayed in the same manner as ones you explicitly create.

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences->Java->Compiler->Task Tags and the other, change the "TODO" entry to "TODO_CONCERN".

Also note the "Clean and redetect tasks"-button.

Comment: Note that I said I'd already changed those.  I also had done the "Clean and redetect".   Makes no diffierence.  The old "TODO" tags are still marked in the right margin area, even though NONE of the Tags lists in preferences include a plain "TODO".

This is with Eclipse 4.3.2